# ReplaceAll giving different answer than actual replacement

Tags: replacement

I have an expression, and I wanted to evaluate it for a certain value of a variable.  However, /. gives a calculation error, whereas manually replacing the variable with the value succeeds.  Why?

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(k+n)! (n-k)!}\text{/.}\, \{k\to 4\}$$
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(n+4)! (n-4)!}$$

The first errors `Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.` and returns `Indeterminate`, whereas the second yields `BesselI[8, 2]`.  My understanding of `ReplaceAll` was that the two should be functionally identical.  What's wrong?

(Mathematica 11.0.1.0, Windows 10, 64 bit)

Comment: Hi Erhannis, welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Could you post the exact code that's exhibiting the issue in copy-pasteable format? It helps a lot if we can just plug your code straight into Mathematica. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be an order of precedence thing.

When you evaluate your first function $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(k+n)! (n-k)!}$, it simplifies to $\frac{\, _1F_2(1;1-k,k+1;1)}{(-k)! k!}$.

Since it will do this simplification *before* replacing $k$, and since ${(-k)! k!}$ evaluates to `ComplexInfinity` (as does the top half of the function), you get the error message.

The trick is to do the replacement earlier:

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{(k+n)! (n-k)!}\text{/.}\, k\to 4\right)$

Which evaluates to `BesselI[8, 2]` as expected.

Comment: This kind of problem is exactly why `HypergeometricPFQRegularized` was introduced. Your general sum formula can be simplified to be non-singular: `Sum[1/((n+k)!(n-k)!), {n,0,Infinity}] // FullSimplify` gives `HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1},{1-k,1+k},1]`, which at `k=4` gives `Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[9,1]`, which in turn fullsimplifies to `BesselI[8,2]`.